# How prevalent is the dock scratching the Nintendo Switch's screen?

Tags: hardware, nintendo-switch

I don't own a Switch yet, but I'm planning for one. One common complaint I hear is that the dock is built in such a way that the screen (rather, it's bezel) is easily scratched when taking the Switch in and out of the dock.

[image: Bezel scratches caused by the Switch dock]

It's to the point where some enterprising gamers are creating "dock socks":

[image: A switch console docked, with a protective fabric insert]

Is the screen really that easily scratched, and should I be investing in a screen protector and dock sock for casual use?

Comment: It really depends on how careful you are in inserting it. If you are a very careful person who treats electronics like sacred religious items, you'll probably avoid scratches. If you don't have time for that and just want to shove it in, you might need a pokéball sock. Or, if you decide that scratches don't diminish your gaming enjoyment, you might just let it scratch.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't worry too much about this. I'm pretty sure a big part of the "scratch fiasco" is websites and YouTube channels looking for ad impressions (and money), unfortunately. I've removed/docked my Switch several times since day 1 and I don't see any scratches or even smears/traces on my screen (with a screen protector).

Looking at my dock, I simply see *no way* the dock alone should be able to scratch the screen, because there are two plastic guides with small rubber pads to keep the screen away from the dock, but they don't really have any sharp edges.

Of course they might in theory still scratch the screen, especially if you're just "throwing" the console into the dock or if there are bigger dust particles in there (maybe even sand from your hands?).

As such I think adding any good quality screen protector should offer you enough protection. It doesn't have to be tempered glass, even just a not too thin foil should be sufficient. If you notice damage on it, replace it, otherwise just enjoy playing.

---

**Edit:** Also, something I noticed the very first time I saw that now "famous" picture of the scratches: Their orientation is completely inconsistent and doesn't make any sense, if you assume the console is inserted in a straight way as intended. Just look at the scratches highlighted with a few lines:

[image: Highlighted Scratches]

This looks – at least to me – very deliberate, rather than random usage. Also wouldn't you assume there to be one or two scratches before you notice them? Rather than waiting for 10-20 to appear?

Comment: It looks like they constantly try to put them in corner first (with a lot of force).

Comment: Can only agree. From my experience, the only way to get scratches on your switch is to smash it into the docking station. Not implying that I tried

Comment: @JMac `It looks like they constantly try to put them in corner first (with a lot of force).` Maybe that person has installed one too many DDR RAM modules?

Comment: @xDaizu Haha that's a pretty good explanation.  Maybe they're still waiting for something to click in place when they forcibly push down on the switch.

Comment: `This looks – at least to me – very deliberate, rather than random usage` I thought exactly the same when I saw the pattern. But, then again... [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon's_razor)

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you're going to do with your Switch.

If you're planning to use it as portable console then you'll just have to buy a charger which will not require to put the Switch in it's dock each times, so no problem.

But if you're like me, and you're going to use it with an external screen then there are a few problems.

I was first expecting to let it in it's dock without taking it out except for rare occasions, but you have to keep in mind that except if you're going to buy a lot of accessories, for example, you'll have to charge your playcons. And to charge them, if your dock is put with your others consoles in a place not that easy to reach, you're going to take off you're Switch, put the playcons on it put it back again until you play next time.

Another thing : you can't totally switch off the console using the menu. So once again, if you want to power it off you'll have to take it off the dock, switch it off and put it back in again.

So I'm someone like @sir adelaide described. I'm really careful with all my consoles, but even after having bought a screen protection, I really dislike this dock as you have to search the right place for the Switch to be well connected and for that, you move the console int it's dock a few times.

I don't have any scratch yet, but I'm sure if they don't release an adapter to connect the console to a screen without the dock, or if I don't buy something to charge my playcons without having to attach them to the Switch, there is bound to be some scratch soon.

Comment: FYI you can just connect/disconnects the Joycons without removing or moving the console. Hold it down and in position with one hand and use the other to connect/disconnect the Joycons. It requires some practice, but it's not that hard.

Comment: Yes you can do that, except if like me, you let the dock near your hdmi switch, next to all your consoles, so : under your desk in a place not so easy to reach.
That's why I say it really depends on a lot of things. But for myself, as I was expecting a fully functional fixed console, I was disappointed by all you need to buy for it to really become a portable console/ or a fixed console.

Comment: You don't have to undock it to turn it off.  You just press the power button on top.  Most of this is also irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Well I do like turning it off really. And by that I mean not only putting it in sleep mode. When you press the button it's only sleep mode as for the menu. If you want to really turn it off you have to press the button for a few seconds, then a menu show on the Switch where you can turn it off. (and I judge that as relevant as for each of that you need to take it off from the dock so might scratch it each time ;))

Comment: @Ise from my experience if you undock the console and turn it off (holding down the power button) it turns itself back on when placed back in the dock.  So taking it out to power it off wouldn't even work if what I'm saying is true.